# How do I use dynamic column names in a loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
(
  A,
  B,
  C,
  D,
)
SELECT id, name1, middlename1, lastname1 FROM Table2
```

I want to put this INSERT INTO statement in a loop where each time I iterate, the columns from Table2 change, such as:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
(
  A,
  B,
  C,
  D,
)
SELECT id, name2, middlename2, lastname2 FROM Table2
```

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT -

`Table2` has the following columns:

```
Name1, Name2, Name3, etc.
```

These need to go into another table as ROWS:

```
Name1

Name2

Name3

...
```

Comment: Can you post your table structure, there are probably better ways to do this?

Comment: Agree with @bluefeet, I think you may not need a loop just for this purpose. If you elaborate more, there could be a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to *unpivot* the table in your table to then insert it. This will convert your converts into rows.

Depending on your version of SQL Server, you have different options.

If you are using SQL Server 2008+, then you can use `CROSS APPLY` and `VALUES`:

```
insert into table1 (A, B, C, D)
select t.id,
  c.col1,
  c.col2,
  c.col3
from yourtable t
cross apply
(
  values 
    (name1, middlename1, lastname1),
    (name2, middlename2, lastname2),
    (name3, middlename3, lastname3)
) c (col1, col2, col3);
```

Or you can use a `UNION ALL` query:

```
insert into table1 (A, B, C, D)
select id, name1 col1, middlename1 col2, lastname1 col3
from yourtable
union all
select id, name2 col1, middlename2 col2, lastname2 col3
from yourtable
union all
select id, name3 col1, middlename3 col2, lastname3 col3
from yourtable
```

Comment: i think the cross apply is what im looking for. gonna give it a try and report back in a few. thanks blue :)